# How to calculate confidence interval for difference (or ratio) of two different time series?

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, nonparametric

I have two time series which are sampled at the exact same times.  I would like to calculate a confidence interval either for the ratio between the two or the difference between the two.  The values tend to be somewhat similar, but both have a large amount of what looks like random noise superimposed on them (much larger than the potential difference, at any particular point in time).  What is the appropriate method to calculate a confidence interval in this case?

P.S. The data is very different from being normal; it is roughly flat-top, pretty similar shape (but perhaps shifted) for the two series.

Comment: Why not compute the ratio, or the difference, and model that time series, forming whatever kind of interval you need, as you would for a univariate series.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks!  Does that lose any statistical power?  Also, how do I form an interval for a univariate series?

Comment: I can't really respond without being more clear about the circumstances. For example, knowing what, exactly you're forming an interval for. If it's a CI, you're presumably forming an interval for some population quantity (like a mean) ... but what quantity?